# C array of structs declaration

Tags: c, arrays, struct

In the Linux kernel, I see a declaration of an array of structs that looks like this

```
struct SomeStructName [] ={
[SOMEWEIRD_NAME] = {
                   .field1 = "some value"
                   },
[SOMEWEIRD_NAME2] = {
                   .field1 = "some value1"
                   },
}
```

I have never seen a declaration like that, specifically I can't figure out what `[SOMEWEIRD_NAME]` means, and why it's used.

Comment: It's a GNU extension for [designated initializers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

Comment: @Kninnug it's not a GNU extension, it is valid C99

Comment: @ouah I thought C99 only allowed the `.field` syntax. It seems I was wrong, though GCC does have some extra syntax not in the standard.

Comment: @Kninnug the range syntax (e.g., `[0..255]`) is a GNU extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a C99 *[designated initializer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Designated_initializers)* for arrays.

For example:

```
/* 
 * Initialize element  0 to 1
 *                     1 to 2
 *                     2 to 3
 *                   255 to 1   
 * and all other elements to 0
 */
int arr[256] = {[0] = 1, 2, 3, [255] = 1};
```

It allows you to initialize some specific array elements in any order and also allows you to omit some elements.

In your example the expression between `[]` can be a macro name for an integer constant expression or an `enum` constant. It cannot be a variable name as it has to be an integer constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure what you meant but i assume `SOMEWEIRD_NAME` is a Define value.

Define is a way to give values another name but it wont take space in you'r memorry on runtime, insted, it will be replaced everywhere the name of that defined values is writen in your code during compiling prosses.

The syntax for deifne is as the following: `#define NAME_OF_DEFINE       80`
in the following example every `NAME_OF_DEFINE` in your code will be replaced whit the values 80. Notice that you shouldn't end the line whit `;`.

In your example i expect `SOMEWEIRD_NAME` to have a numbric value to set the array's size.

You can fine more information about `#define` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The "SOMEWEIRD_NAME" is most likely either a #define whose value is a number, or it's an enumeration, whose numeric value is its position in the enumeration.

Comment: Yeah in my case it was actually an enum which is interpreted as an integer by the compiler so SOMEWEIRD_NAME turns into 0